# Appending to $PATH vs using aliases: Which is better?

Tags: path, alias, bash

In at least some cases, aliases and adding $PATH locations can be used interchangeably. For example, looking at the python tool [couchapp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp), I need to either alias the executable ([as helpfully described here](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/pull/240)) or make the executable available via $PATH.

These are the two lines that can achieve this:

```
alias couchapp="~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/couchapp"
```

OR

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/
```

Is there a very definite 'better' option of these two? Why or why not?

Comment: Another option is to put a symlink to the executable in a directory already in your path. Or just move the executable into such a directory. (`~/bin` is often a good choice).

Comment: Thanks. If I symlink a folder with an executable would that work? I.e. Would sub directories of a $PATH directory be searched?

Comment: subdirectories are not searched.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- **An alias is a *shell* feature**: any environment that invokes utilities *directly*, without involving a *shell* will *not* see aliases.

  - Note: Even when calling *shell* commands from languages such as Python (using, e.g., `os.system()`), user-specific shell initialization files are typically *not* called, so user-specific aliases *still* won't be visible.
- **A directory added to the `$PATH` *environment variable* is respected by any process that tries to invoke an executable by *mere filename***, whether via a shell or not.

  - Similarly, this assumes that any calling process sees the `$PATH` environment-variable additions of interest, so additions made by the *user-specific* initialization files are typically *not* seen, *unless* the calling process was launched from an *interactive shell*.

#### Lookup cost

If you know that a shell will be involved in invoking your utility, you can keep overhead down by defining *aliases* that invoke your executables by their full path.
Of course, you need to do this for *each* executable you want to be callable by name only.

By contrast, adding directories to the `$PATH` variable potentially increases the overhead of locating a given executable by *mere filename*, because all directories listed must be searched one by one until one containing an executable by the specified name is found (if any).

#### Precedence

If a shell is involved, aliases take precedence over `$PATH` lookups.
Of course, later alias definitions can override earlier ones.

If no shell is involved or no alias by a given name exists, `$PATH` lookups happen in the order in which the directories are listed in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

As your example shows, `$PATH` allows you to do one line for all of your executables in that location. For that reason I use the latter option. You can also chain many `$PATH` statements together, allowing you to easily add many more locations to your "executables" from the command line.

If for some reason you do not want to make all of the executables available `alias` would be better.